# Program cannot read all json files, reads onla a few of them

Tags: python, json, pandas

I try to make a DataFrame with all the json files in the path but when I run the program it writes only the data in a few files instead of all in the DataFrame. The program runs without errors. Do you know why this happens?

here is the code

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import os

path = 'C:\\Users\\sotir\\Desktop\\machinedataset'
filenames = os.listdir(path)
dfs=[]

for filename in sorted(filenames):
    
        fullpath = os.sep.join((path, filename))
        f = open(fullpath)
        js = json.load(f)
        f.close()
        df= pd.json_normalize(js['playlists'], meta=['name', 'collaborative', 'pid', 'modified_at','num_tracks', 'num_albums',
                                              'num_followers', 'num_edits', 'duration_ms', 'num_artists'],record_path= ['tracks'],
                       record_prefix='_')
        dfs.append(df)
        
        
dfs= pd.concat(dfs)
            
        
        

dfs = dfs.reindex(columns=['name', 'collaborative', 'pid', 'modified_at','num_tracks', 'num_albums',
                                              'num_followers', 'num_edits', 'duration_ms', 'num_artists', '_pos', '_artist_name',
                         '_track_uri','_artist_uri','_track_name', '_album_uri', 'duration_ms', '_album_name'])

dfs
```

this is the output[this the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mi1DT.png)

As you can see the pid begins with pid 0 because the first file in the path contains it but the last pid is 999999 and the program outputs only up to pid 9999.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Is there a particular reason you expect the `pid` values to be in ascending order in the resulting DataFrame? I think you should be expecting your data to be in order according to the order in which the files were opened, and nothing to do with any of the data in those files.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and try to set up an example that other people can try to see the problem you describe. Also, please only use tags that are related to *the question you are asking about*, not the context that explains why you have the code. I have removed the `[machine-learning]` tag.

Comment: Note that closing a file like this means that if there is an exception with json.load then close() won't be called. Using "with" is best practice for reading files.

Comment: I changed the code using with but the result is the same.

Comment: You didn't post the exception trace. The exception is usually a pretty good indicator of what went wrong. Is it being thrown from json.loads or from pandas.json_normalize?

Comment: Thanks for your response Kenny, there is no exception but the program reads only a few files from the path instead of all the files and this is the problem.